# Mailchimp - how to resize a table and hide elements when the browser shrinks - html/css

Tags: html, css, resize, mailchimp

Okay so I've bought a theme for mailchimp and need to modify it slightly for my own personal use. The html is written in tables.
What i am aiming for, is the background image in the header of the page (top table), to resize when the browser shrinks down to mobile size.

So far i have been able to achieve the shrinking of the image (through the use of setting width to 100% and not setting a height), although, when the browser is shrunk down to mobile size, the purple body behind the image overflows underneath the image (like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCRK5.png), when do not want to see any background at all. Along with this, on shrinking, I am trying to get the title, text, and read more button to scale down with the image, and have the logo and all top links hidden.

I have tried playing around with max-height and max-width, setting overflow to hidden, and trying to re-do the whole thing using a div container instead of a table, but it got way too complicated. I have no knowledge of javascript or jquery so a html/css solution is preferred.

Here is the code for the main section that i'm trying to shrink -

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container800">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="background-image: url(http://pickedmail.com/mira/img/main-bg.png); background-size: 100%; background-position: top center; background-repeat: repeat;" background="http://pickedmail.com/mira/img/main-bg.png">

                        <table border="0" align="center" width="590" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container590 bodybg_color">

                            <tr><td height="30" style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="container590">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                                                    <tr><td height="5" style="font-size: 5px; line-height: 5px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                                    <tr>
```

here is the full thing in jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jackgenesin/2zzkrqzf/

Any help appreciated, feel free to tell me its way too complicated to do purely in html/css haha, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The purple body has nothing to do with the image. That's coming from the `bgcolor="8a5a8d"`in the first `<table>` tag in your fiddle. You could eliminate that and the color would go away.

With the code you've posted, you've got explicit pixel widths declared in the first two `<table>` tags. This tells a browser that these shouldn't be resized. You need to use a relative dimension (e.g. 100%) to make this work. Better still add this css: `style="max-width=800px;" so the table doesn't get too big on desktops.

Since you've got nested tables to make this layout (something that still is required for many email clients), to really stop the header image from spilling over into the message body, you'd have to create two sets of nested tables one after the other. If that's too much work, change the `background-size:` parameter to `cover`. That will stretch the image to fill the background, cropping edges if needed to make everything fit.

Finally, to really achieve everything you want, with the auto-hiding logos and shrinking menus, you need to make your template [responsive](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/). Take a look at the free mailchimp templates for code you might be able to reuse for this.

And you **will** have to do all this in HTML/CSS, since you can't rely on an email client allowing javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Although, since posting I have fixed it myself by very simply removing the width 100%, adding a min-height of 100% and adding a background-position cover (like you suggested also). This has given me the desired result. But thank you!